# How do I allow multiple users to connect to my H2 database simultaneously?

Tags: java, sql, database, h2

I am using H2 for database management, and this is what I would like to do:

I would like to allow multiple users to access a database at the same time. I've read a bit about "MULTI_THREADED=TRUE", "LOCK_FILE=NO", and "AUTO_SERVER=TRUE". I've also read that "LOCK_FILE=NO" can be dangerous, because it can corrupt the database. I definitely would not want this, so I'm assuming that is a bad way to go. I've also tried to close the connection immediately after a record is accessed, whether it is being read from or written to. So far, nothing seems to work. The application is not allowing me to read from or write to the database if the database has been connected to in a separate instance of the application (ex: on another computer). Once I completely close the application on one computer, I am able to access the database records.

How do I allow multiple users to connect to the H2 database at the same time without compromising the safety of the database?

Comment: Funny how the first answer you get is exactly what I've been saying...

Comment: Not exactly. None of your responses were very direct or helpful.

Comment: So "use the server mode" wasn't helpful...shame

Comment: Okay, I don't think using "AUTO_SERVER=TRUE" alone fixed the problem. Should that alone have fixed the problem? Right now, I have it set up to immediately commit and close the connection after a query is made, so the lock file is created and then deleted. Is this an efficient way to allow multiple users to access the database?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like you are using H2 in embedded mode, which only allows one database connection at a time. See [connection modes](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes) in the documentation for details.

If you need support for multiple connections, including from multiple application instances, then you need to start H2 in [server mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server) instead and use the appropriate [connection URLs](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url) for this mode.

Comment: So, is there a way to use "AUTO_SERVER=TRUE" to do this? Would that make it mixed?

Comment: And, if I make the Auto Server true, would that allow multiple connections?

Comment: The [automatic mixed mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode) (i.e. AUTO_SERVER=TRUE) allows multiple concurrent connections to the database. However, I wouldn't recommend it, due to the constraints that the first connection starts the server and when that connection is closed, so is the server and all remote connections are therefore closed, and pending transactions will be rolled back.

Comment: But if I use "connection.commit()", I won't have that problem, correct?

Comment: The documentation states that in embedded mode there is no limit on the number of open connections.

Comment: @StefanNeuhaus but not by multiple users

Answer (score 7):

**AUTO_SERVER=TRUE** allows multiple connections mode.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is wrong. It is possible to have multiple connections without starting a separate H2 server manually by using [Automatic Mixed Mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode):

> Multiple processes can access the same database without having to start the server manually. To do that, append ;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE to the database URL. You can use the same database URL independent of whether the database is already open or not. This feature doesn't work with in-memory databases.

So, to allow multiple users to connect to an H2 database simultaneously, append `;AUTO_SERVER=true` data source URL property.

The only caveat is that you can't use this with the in-memory database. The next best thing (based on simplicity) is file-based database.

---

**Example for a spring app**

`application.properties` to use a file-based database:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/testdb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

When launching the app this will create a new database file as `./data/testdb.mv.db` or use it if it already exists.

Now you can connect to this database from another source using the same url `h2:file:./data/testdb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE`. It's important not to forget to append `;AUTO_SERVER=true` to the url when connecting from another source, otherwise you will get `The file is locked` exception.